# Solving the Schrodinger equation for an infinite well with asymmetric wells or multiple wells

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know how to solve the Schrodinger equation for an infinite well where I set the well to be to 0 potential between x = 0 and L and infinite potential outside these regions. I am curious whether  you could solve the equation if I set the well from something like x between 0.3 to 0.8 or similar asymmetric situation. I tried to solve the equation but found that I could never get sine/cosine to go to zero on one end of the well. Is there any way around this or do we always have to set the well such that x=0 for the beginning of the well?
For reference the reason I think it is not possible is:

$$\psi(x)=A\sin(kx)$$
$$0.3k=n\pi$$
$$k=n/{0.3\pi}$$
$$ A\sin(0.8k) \neq 0\space for \space k=n/{0.3\pi}$$

So what happens in the case for example where I have two infinite wells, one between 0 and 2 and another between 3 and 4.3? How could I describe the two wavefunctions using the same co-ordinate system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the potential well is given to be the interval $x\in[a,b]$, you may always define new coordinates $y = x-a$. In these coordinates, the well is given by the interval $y\in[0,L]$ where $L\equiv b-a$.  The Schrodinger equation remains the same:
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi = E\psi  \iff -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dy^2} \psi = E\psi$$
$$\implies \psi = A\sin(ky)+ B\cos(ky) \qquad k \equiv \sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}$$
Apply your boundary conditions, find your eigenfunctions, and then at the very end make the substitution $y = x+a$.

If you have two completely separate wells, then they are completely independent. You're just solving the same problem twice on the same sheet of paper - without any coupling between the wells, the solutions are the same except the wavefunction of the second well has a shifted coordinate.